# ASP.NET Core 6 Web API - ContentDisposition response header

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, http-headers, content-disposition

I FOUND THE SOLUTION!

```
public async Task<IAactionResult> Export(ExportType fileType)
{
    var result = await _someService.ExportAsync(fileType);

    var fileResult = new FileContentResult(result.Content,contentType)
            {
                FileDownloadName = result.FileName,
            };

    return fileResult;
}
```

I have an `ExportResult` class:

```
public class ExportResult
{
    public string FileName { get; set; } = null!;
    public byte[] Content { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And I have an `Export` method in a controller:

```
public async Task<ExportResult> Export(ExportType fileType)
{
    var result = await _someService.ExportAsync(fileType);
    return result;
}
```

The problem is the `content-disposition` response header didn't show up.

I tried to add to cors with these, but it doesn't work.

```
.WithExposedHeaders("content-disposition");
.WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
```

Comment: Good to see that you find the answer. However, you should write the solution in the answer post but not add to the question post. After post the answer, don't forget to accept the answer when it is available. Thanks.

Comment: Onece i written an solution to answer post and lot of person said it is not good and i need to EDIT the original post ._.